# 403 USER DOES NOT HAVE THE RIGHT ROLES. when use facebook login

Tags: laravel, facebook

I create Facebook login and it's working fine. Customer who login via Facebook will get the user role.

But when that customer go to the page that inside middleware role user, it shows 403  USER DOES NOT HAVE THE RIGHT ROLES. (Normal user can pass it) How can I fix it?

Below is my code.

web.php

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:user']], function () {
        Route::get('/colors', function () {     return view('dashboard.colors'); });
    });
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('facebook.login');
    Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/notes';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Redirect the user to the GitHub authentication page.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

            // All providers...     
            $saveUser = User::updateOrCreate([
                'facebook_id' => $user->getId()
            ],[
                'name' => $user->getName(),
                'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                'password' => Hash::make($user->getName().'@'.$user->getId()),
                'remember_token' => $user->token
            ]);
     
            Auth::loginUsingId($saveUser->id);
     
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.homepage');
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
               throw $th;
            }
    }
    
}
```

login.blade.php

```
                      <a href="{{ route('facebook.login') }}" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                          <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i>
                          Login with Facebook
                      </a>
```

Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddFacebookIdInUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('facebook_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('facebook_id');
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to assign the user role when a user is created through Facebook login?

Comment: In model file (user.php), I have   protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'image', 'facebook_id']; and  protected $attributes = ['menuroles' => 'user']; Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Nuttapong Makong(https://www.facebook.com/groups/371993079543385/user/100000205153497/) to answer this question. I have to add the code below in controller file.

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
    use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
```

And in handleProviderCallback function

```
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

            // All providers...     
            $saveUser = User::updateOrCreate([
                'facebook_id' => $user->getId()
            ],[
                'name' => $user->getName(),
                'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                'password' => Hash::make($user->getName().'@'.$user->getId()),
                'remember_token' => $user->token
            ]);
     
            if(!($saveUser ->hasRole('user'))){
                $role = Role::where('name','user')->first();
                $saveUser ->assignRole([$role->id]);
            }

            Auth::loginUsingId($saveUser->id);
     
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.homepage');
            } catch (\Throwable $th) {
               throw $th;
            }
    }
```